# HADOOP - Problems copying text files into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, word-count

I am implementing Hadoop single-node-cluster following the prominent [Michael Noll Tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/). The cluster is working, checking with `jps` shows that all components are running after execution of `start-all.sh`.

I face a problem reproducing the wordcount-example using some downloaded texts. I downloaded the files in `/tmp/gutenberg` and checked if they are there, which seems to be the case:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /tmp/gutenberg/
insgesamt 3604
-rw-r----- 1 hduser hadoop  674570 Mai  7 01:03 pg20417.txt
-rw-r----- 1 hduser hadoop 1573151 Mai  7 01:03 pg4300.txt
-rw-r----- 1 hduser hadoop 1423803 Mai  7 01:03 pg5000.txt
```

Then I start the Hadoop cluster as instructed in the tutorial and then execute the following:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
copyFromLocal: `/user/hduser/gutenberg': No such file or directory
```

Obviously there is no file `/user/hduser/gutenberg`, so I created it with the following:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

And then re-ran the copyFromLocal order without any errors. If I then check if the files are there I get:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser/gutenberg
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-05-07 02:22 /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg
```

So, as you see, the text files are **not** there. If I re-run the copyFromLocal command I get a message that the files **are** there:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
copyFromLocal: `/user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg/pg20417.txt': File exists
copyFromLocal: `/user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg/pg4300.txt': File exists
copyFromLocal: `/user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg/pg5000.txt': File exists
```

I don't understand what's wrong here and would very appreciate any help to solve this!

Comment: You need to go down one more directory. Alternatively, you can use `-lsr` to list files in the directory tree. `-lsr` searches the directories recursively.

Comment: Thanks, a useful commanf for me (a newbie to Linux and Hadoop! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg` and you should see all files, you are using the `ls` command wrong, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

This is your copy command to copy data from local filesystem to HDFS filesystem.
In your command your local filesystem path is **/tmp/gutenberg** and HDFS filesystem path is  **/user/hduser/gutenberg**. It means you are copying entire **gutenberg** directory from local to given HDFS directory. **`copyFromLocal`** command is used to copy files and directory from local filesystem to HDFS filesystem and when you triggered it first time it copied your directory along with files into HDFS directory.

**`copyFromLocal`** command doesn't permit to override the files on HDFS so when you are running it second time you are getting **File Exists** error.

When you do `hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg/`, you will be able to see your files there.

You can also use **`-put`** command instead of **`-copyFromLocal`** to copy data from local filesystem to HDFS filesystem.

`hadoop dfs`  is deprecated so I suggest to use `hdfs dfs` for your further operation related to hadoop.

Comment: My problem was apparently coused while creating the `/user/hduser/gutenberg` directory. I need the test files to be in this directory, but the copyFromLocal command creates another folder called gutenberg which contains the text files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**1. Remove existing directory:**

```
hadoop fs -rm -R /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

**2. Create directory:**

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg
```

**3. Use put command to upload files into hdfs:**

```
hadoop fs -put /tmp/gutenberg/*.* /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg
```

**4. Now, list files in hdfs:**

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg
```

You should now see all the files.